# What's the equivalent of window.reload() in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

Is there a way to completely refresh an entire scene in react-native without updating the state or forcing a re-render?

For example:

```
refreshButton(){
    Actions.refresh()
}
```

P.S: I am using react-native-router-flux as my navigator. I did try `Actions.refresh({key: "page_name"})` but it did not work.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I want to refresh a listview whenever the phone gets reconnected to the internet again. @Scimonster

Comment: So you need to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';
// component did mount
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
    'change',
    this._handleConnectivityChange
);

_handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
this.setState({
  isConnected,
});
};
// remove listener on componentWillUnmount
```

more info [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/netinfo.html)